# php time and date function

Tags: php, datetime

I have a quickie here,
Whenever I try to echo out the time in `hours:min:sec` using the `date()` function everything works perfect.
But when I try echoing it out using a variable with a value, it always adds up 2 hours.

Take a look at the code:

```
$time = time();

$past = 120;

//this works perfectly

echo $time = date("H:i:s",$time);

//but this doesnt. it adds 2 hours.

echo $time = date("H:i:s",$time);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out what You are doing:

```
//You are assigning a string to $time variable

echo $time = date("H:i:s",$time);

//second call - trying to format date from unix timestamp, which actually is a string with some hours, minutes and seconds

echo $time = date("H:i:s",$time);
```

**EDIT**

Maybe You mean this?

```
$time = time();
$past = 120;
echo date("H:i:s",$time);
echo date("H:i:s",$time - $past);
```

Comment: what am trying to do is format date from unix timestamp, that is what am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] )
```

On second using of "date" function, second param is string. Like that 01:01:01. But it must be integer. So converting 01:01:01 to integer; it will be "0". What's your purpose?

Comment: all am trying to do is converting from timestamp to readable format

Comment: example: 3600 in timestamp = 01:00:00 in 24 hours system

Comment: echo date("H:i:s"); // prints now. 01:39:02. echo date("H:i:s", time()); // prints now. 01:39:02. echo date("H:i:s", mktime("01","39","02", "17", "03", "2011")); // prints now. 01:39:02.

Comment: great, i got a better understanding of mktime :)